# Responsive iframe carousel modal?

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, popupwindow

I want to add to my Tumblr a popup/modal div-based carousel (for lack of a better term--I don't want a simple image carousel) that is navigable via a bottom-aligned menu, either directly in the modal or as an iframe. Having not been able to find resources to build it the former way, I opted for the latter. While viewport units seem to make the to-be-iframed page generally correctly width-responsive (there is an increasing right offset that larger vw's won't fix), height-responsiveness breaks when I either resize the source page or stuff it into the final modal, preventing me from accessing the navigation menu. How can I make the iframe carousel properly size-responsive; or can someone point me to the proper way to build a popup div carousel? Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qx2fdp5/3/) for my dilemma, as well as [the iframed page](https://hotheadhero.tumblr.com/test1) (code accessible via [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/13ZYAv6F)).

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="changer changer1 active" data-slidey="1"><span>ITEM 1</span></li><!--
        --><li class="changer changer2" data-slidey="2"><span>ITEM 2</span></li><!--
        --><li class="changer changer3" data-slidey="3"><span>ITEM 3</span></li><!--
  --><li class="changer changer4" data-slidey="4"><span>ITEM 4</span></li>
  <li class="changer changer5" data-slidey="5"><span>ITEM 5</span></li>
</ul>

    <div id="carousel" class="slidey1"><!--
  --><div class="box">
<iframe frameborder="0" id="owl" scrolling="yes" src="URL" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div><!--
  --><div class="box">
<iframe frameborder="0" id="owl" scrolling="yes" src="URL" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div><!--
  --><div class="box">
<iframe frameborder="0" id="owl" scrolling="yes" src="URL" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div><!--
  --><div class="box">
<iframe frameborder="0" id="owl" scrolling="yes" src="URL" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div><!--
  --><div class="box">
<iframe frameborder="0" id="owl" scrolling="yes" src="URL" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
        #main {
            background:#fff;
            border:1px solid #eaeaea;
            height:100vw;
            width:100vw;
            text-align:center;
            padding:25px;
            font-family:'open sans', sans-serif;
            font-size:11px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        ul#nav {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            list-style:none;
            width:100vw;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0vw;
            padding-top:15px;
            border-top:1px solid #eaeaea;
            color:#222;
            display:flex;
        }
        ul#nav li {
            display:inline-block;
            width:100px;
            overflow:hidden;
            line-height:20px;
            font-size:11px;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            letter-spacing:1.1px;
            cursor:pointer;
            position:relative;
            font-weight:bold;
            flex:1;
        }

[...]

        #carousel {
            width:500vw;
            position:absolute;
            top:10px;
            text-align:left;
        }
        .slidey1 {
            margin-left: 0vw;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
            transition: all 0.3s linear;
        }

        /* my actual code contains 5 different slidey# classes, with the slidey number increasing by 1 (up 
           to .slidey4) and the margin-left decreasing by 100vw (down to -400vw) */

        .box {
            height:92vh;
            padding:0 15px;
            display:inline-block;
            width:94.5vw;
            vertical-align:top;
            margin-right:25px;
            text-align:center;
        }
```

JS:

```
       (function($){ $(document).ready(function(){ $("[title],a[title],img[title]").style_my_tooltips({ tip_follows_cursor:true, tip_delay_time:100, tip_fade_speed:300, attribute:"title" }); }); })(jQuery);
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".changer").click(function(){
            $("#carousel").removeClass();
            $("#carousel").addClass("slidey" + $(this).data("slidey"));
            $(".changer1, .changer2, .changer3, .changer4, .changer5").removeClass("active");
            $(".changer" + $(this).data("slidey")).addClass("active");
            return false;
        });
          $('ul.tags li a').on({
           mouseenter: function() {
               $(this).parent().addClass('hovered');
           },
           mouseleave: function() {
               $(this).parent().removeClass('hovered');
           }
       });
      })
```

Thank you!

Comment: I was inspired to try this again after seeing [this 3-yr-old post](https://octomoosey.tumblr.com/post/137697402257) on Tumblr that describes how to add something similar , but one attempt at adding this to my busy site code didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to make a CSS-only (vertical, but it shouldn't be difficult to make it horizontal) carousel that, if pulled off right, should be able to make modal/iframe usage completely unnecessary. If anyone else should be interested, this is the tutorial I found: https://yeolithm.com/carousel/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

So if i get it right you want a good carousel inside of a modal you made..

And as I can see your are using JQuery Library. So here's a responsive and easy library for making a carousel, it's called Owl Carousel, and i have used it a lot in my projects.

[Owl Carousel link](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)

**Edit: here's a live example of owl carousel:**

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <item>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="">
  </item>
  <item>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="">
  </item>
  <item>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="">
  </item>
  <item>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="">
  </item>
  <item>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="">
  </item>
  <item>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="">
  </item>
</div>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Edit:

You can change the number of items you want to see on any screen by editing the responsive object, example :

responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }

[[Source/Docs]](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html)

Comment: Hmm, even if I insert css defining each class you used as 100% or 100 viewport units tall or wide, the image won't scale; and multiple copies of the one image display on browser window AND Tumblr modal without me doing anything. I was wondering if it was possible to make a single item on the carousel automatically scale to fill the viewport (browser window or whatever allotted space in the modal) and then be navigable by a custom n-item menu (rather than arrows or dots).

Comment: you can change the carousel to view a single image instead of 5 or 3 (Update my post for the info about how)..

Comment: and for the navigation can i be more specific? Do you want a custom navigation buttons?

Comment: Yeah, custom navigation buttons in a manner of speaking. Notice how on the "iframed page" link I posted, there's a separate area of text that you can click the titles of t o navigate to different (text or internally-iframed page) sections of the carousel.